# How to update gridview datasource binding at runtime in mvvm framework?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, devexpress

I have bind list of MainModelList object with gridview datasource and when I click on button barButtonItemValidate I already update object in MainModel list but the gridview datasource is not update or refresh.
so how to make gridview datasource update at runtime?

```
    //View
    _fluent = mvvmContext.OfType<MainViewModel>();
    _fluent.SetBinding(gridControlView, g => g.DataSource, x => x.MainObjectList);
    _fluent.BindCommand(barButtonItemValidate, x => x.Update());
    //ViewModel
    public MainModelList MainObjectList { get; set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MainObjectList = new MainModelList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are replacing the entire list. make the MainObjectList property virtual to make it `INotifyPropertyChanged` [aware](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/117014/Build-an-Application/WinForms-MVVM/Concepts/Conventions-and-Attributes#properties):

```
// ViewModel
public virtual MainModelList MainObjectList { 
    get; 
    protected set; // changing allowed from the ViewModel's side only
}
```

This change allows performing the grid control's data source update via binding.

If you are changing the single object from the MainObjectList collection, ensure that these changes **provide notifications** either at the entire collection and/or at the specific collection' item level.
The simplest way of accomplishing this task is deriving your collection from the BindingList where T implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
public class MainObjectList : BindingList<MainObject> {
    // ....
}
public class MainObject : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    // ...
}
```

The BindingList will track containing objects and raise the `ListChanged` notification. These notifications will be handled by the gridView and as result,  gridView' display values will be updated.